# Live updating div with xlsx.js

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a basic webpage, with a number of divs. I'm using the xlsx.js package to read data from a number of xlsx files, stored on the webpage's server (i.e. in the web page's root directory). I'm polling the xlsx files every second to monitor for changes.

Below is a basic representation of my code:

The HTML div setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xlsx.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="main_div">STARTING STRING</div>
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window, document, undefined) {
        window.onload = run;

        function run() {
            var Source = "Data.xlsx";
            var GetData = new XMLHttpRequest();
            GetData.open("GET", Source, true);
            GetData.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            GetData.onload = function(e) {
                //Receive and process XLSX data into an array
                //Assign 'Cell' as a particular cell in the worksheet
                var Cell = Worksheet['A1'];
                var CellValue = Cell.v;

                //Assign CellValue to the div
                document.getElementById('main_div').innerHTML = CellValue;

                //Start a 1 second poll
                var DataPoll = setTimeout(run, 1000);
            }

            GetData.send();

        }

    })(window, document, undefined);
</script>
```

The issue I'm having is that when saving changes to cell A1 in the worksheet (on the server itself), main_div (on the client webpage) doesn't always update to the new value. Even on refreshing the client webpage, it will often retain the previous value of A1. I thought this might be a cache issue, so I've used all the required cache-control HTML meta parameters.

Should I be clearing the div at the start of the run() function?

EDIT: Some further clarifications. I've been running the webpage on the server itself (localhost), to eliminate the possibility of it being a server connection issue. I've checked the IIS log files, which show only 200 and 304 HTTP status codes.

I've checked the network requests in Chrome Developer Tools, which has highlighted what I initially believed to be the problem. The Data.xlsx file isn't actually being checked each second. It's 'checking' the file from the cache (HTTP Status Code), which would obviously not contain any changes made to the Excel file.

Given that this indeed looks like a cache issue, and that I've already got all the HTML meta cache-control characteristics set, are there additional steps I can take to prevent any caching of the .xlsx file?

[image]

Comment: you write "stored locally on the webpages server" but the HTML page and JS is parsed on the client, so that must be "stored remotely, on the webpage's" server??

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx I think that you are confusing some issues: your webserver is "Remote" your browser is "local" this JS runs "locally" which means that you can manipulate an XLS file locally, not remotely (on the webserver). if you want to show something from an excel file on your server in your webpage, you should consider a proper Database instead. if you allowed everyone to alter a file on your server directly, you open yourself to hacking. Please either update the question, or reconsider what you are doing

Comment: I didn't explain it very well, my apologies. The client is able to view the div, which holds the xlsx data. The xlsx file itself is stored on the server, and is 'manipulated' programmatically on the server itself; there is no manipulation of the xlsx file by the client.

Comment: so the problem is communication with the server?

Comment: That would make sense, but the issue persists even when running the file in a browser on the server itself, i.e. localhost.

Comment: how about your access.log - does it show the request to update?

Comment: I'll have to check in the morning, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: could you update the question so we can clean up these comments? also - have a look at the developer console on your browser (press F12 - works in FF, IE, Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you evade caching by using

```
var Source = "Data.xlsx?" + new Date().getTime();
```

?

Comment: This is so simple, yet it seems to work! Can you explain how it works? I understand how it evades caching (unique Source address each time, etc.). Is any content following the question mark read as metadata, and therefore not actually read as part of the address?

Comment: It seems data is cached using full URL of the file, including the querystring parameters (data after the ?). So modifying the string makes every file a different resource to cache.